# Cannot get one complete copy of Python multiprocessing array output

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I wrote trivial Python multiprocessing to test how it works:  [Multiprocessing only works for the first iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263630/multiprocessing-only-works-for-the-first-iteration) .I wrapped some array inside a function, then I called multiprocessing map to process it using 5 processor. All that was fine except the output which is 5 copies of each array. Any idea of how to return one instance of each array instead of five instances. I wondering if there is a general way to make the processes communicate with each other.

```py
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

B=np.full((5,4,4),np.nan)
C=np.full((5,4,4),np.nan)
D=np.full((5,4,4),np.nan)


def job1(i):
    print(i)
    A=np.ones((4,4))
    B[i,:,:]=A+1
    C[i,:,:]=2*A+2
    D[i,:,:]=A+5
    return B,C,D
#%%

P=mp.Pool(5)
result=P.map(job1,np.arange(5))
P.close()
P.join()



result[0] 
(array([[[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
         [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
         [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
         [ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.]],

        [[nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan]],

        [[nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan]],

        [[nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan]],

        [[nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan],
         [nan, nan, nan, nan]]]),
```

Comment: multiple processes do not share state

Comment: Thanks, so how could multiprocessing be beneficial in that way.

Comment: You could make a productive start by reading the documentation such as https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html which describes various ways of getting information between processes. Did you read it?