# how to properly start parallel executing of two functions over multiple arguments?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, process-pool

I am looking for a way to start two functions in parallel, each executing over a given set of different arguments. I use `pool.map` to achieve this. I create two different processes and each process starts a pool executing the `map`. This works - the order of execution is a little bit wild, but I will save this for another question.

Now I have also found another approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6976372/mulitprocess-pools-with-different-functions) (see the first answer). They are using only one pool and call `map_async` two times in a row. So I was wondering, if there is a preferred way for doing this?
Because I have read (sadly I don't remember where) that it is best to only use one pool, which would mean the second approach (using only one pool) is better. But when I measure the time, the first approch (using two pools in separate processes) is actually a little bit faster. Additionally in the first approach the functions are really running in parallel, whereas in the second approach first the first call of `map_async` executes, then the second call.

Here is my test code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import time
import os

multiple_pools = True
data = list(range(1, 11))


def func_a(param):
    print(f'running func_a in process {os.getpid()}')
    print(f'passed argument: {param}')
    print('calculating...\n')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    print('done\n')

def func_b(param):
    print(f'running func_b in process {os.getpid()}')
    print(f'passed argument: {param}')
    print('calculating...\n')
    time.sleep(2.5)
    print('done\n')

def execute_func(func, param):
    p = Pool(processes=8)
    with p:
        p.map(func, param)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not multiple_pools:
        t0 = time.time()
        p = Pool(processes=8)

        res = p.map_async(func_a, data)
        res = p.map_async(func_b, data)

        p.close()
        p.join()

        t1 = time.time()
        dt = t1 -t0
        print(f'time spent with one pool: {dt} s')

    else:
        t0 = time.time()
        p1 = Process(target=execute_func, args=(func_a, data))
        p2 = Process(target=execute_func, args=(func_b, data))

        p1.start()
        p2.start()

        p1.join()
        p2.join()
        p1.close()
        p2.close()

        t1=time.time()
        dt = t1 -t0
        print(f'time spent with two pools, each inside an own process: {dt} s')
```

So again, my question: is there one way preferred over the other? Or maybe even other/better ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am assuming when you use two pools that you will be using the non-blocking `map_async` method. I would say that two pools of size N each where you were submitting M tasks to each pool where all the tasks are identical (i.e. require the same resources as far as CPU, I/O, etc. are concerned) should be *more-or-less* equivalent execution time-wise as submitting the same 2 * M tasks to a single pool of size 2 * N.

The following program demonstrates the two cases:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

QUARTER_SECOND_ITERATIONS = 5_000_000

def quarter_second(x):
    sum = 0
    for _ in range(QUARTER_SECOND_ITERATIONS):
        sum += 1
    return x * x

def callback(result):
    global callback_count
    print('Two pools result:', result)
    callback_count += 1
    if callback_count == 2:
        # Both map-async calls have completed:
        print('Two pools time:', time.time() - start_time)

# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data1 = range(10)
    data2 = range(10, 20)
    # Two pools:
    pool1 = Pool(4)
    pool2 = Pool(4)
    callback_count = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    pool1.map_async(quarter_second, data1, callback=callback)
    pool2.map_async(quarter_second, data2, callback=callback)
    pool1.close()
    pool1.join()
    pool2.close()
    pool2.join()

    # One Pool:
    data = range(20)
    pool = Pool(8)
    start_time = time.time()
    result = pool.map(quarter_second, data)
    print('One pool result:', result)
    print('One pool time:', time.time() - start_time)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Prints:

```
Two pools result: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
Two pools result: [100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361]
Two pools time: 1.4994373321533203
One pool result: [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361]
One pool time: 1.4596436023712158
```

I reran this several times and *most* but not all times the one-pool case did slightly better. But I have many other processes running on my desktop that affect the results. I did not include in the total time the actual time to create the processing pool(s). Also, the the map functions, depending on the size of the pools and *iterable* arguments, could compute a slightly different *chunksize* value to use when no explicit *chunksize* argument is specified as is the case here. But that would have a negligible performance effect. **All in all, I can't really see any significant performance difference between the one-pool and two-pool approach given my assumptions.**

Comment: Does this answer your question or did I miss the point of what you were asking?

Comment: yeah, perfect, thanks for your answer and especially the example code! :) So there isn't really a difference between both methods. I'm just learning the basics, because I will need this for a project. Till now I have just been concerned with other things, so sorry for the late reply